# Are they the same formulas?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I was wondering if the below formulas are the same in a logical sense? Could I use the first one instead of the second and vice versa?

1. $\forall x  (P(x) \implies \exists y Q(y))$
2. $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \implies Q(y))$

Comment: why the colon? "⟹" is just an implication ? P is a predicate?

Comment: By Prenex notation you can use the two formulas interchangeably

Comment: Colons are only notation issue. I removed them. Yes - $\implies$ it's an implication and $P, Q$ are predicates.

Comment: In (1) do you mean "$(\forall x(P(x)))\implies (\exists y(Q(y)))$" instead? (That more closely matches what you had initially.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I added parenthesis to determine it. I need to say somthing like: "For every state $x$ if the $P(x)$ is true, then exists the other state $y$ (the state after the x) when $Q(y)$ is true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Prenex normal form. They are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

1 implies 2: Suppose 1. If $P(x)$ is false for all x then 2 is true. Otherwise $P(x)$ is true for at least one $x_0$ hence by 1 there exists $y_0$ such that $Q(y_0)$ is true. Now let $x$, the there exists $y$ (namely $y_0$) such that $P(x)$ implies $Q(y)$ therefore 2.

2 implies 1: Suppose 2. Let $x$, then there exists $y_0$ such that $P(x)$ implies $Q(y_0)$. In particular, if $P(x)$ is true then there exists $y$ (namely $y_0$) such that $Q(y)$ is true.

Hence 1 and 2 are indeed logically equivalent.